# How to search for item type in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm trying to find only mails with the search in Outlook (2012/2010) - I don't want to find calendar entries, notes etc.

I couldn't find anything in the [search reference](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/searchcommands.htm) - something like `"type:mail"`.

Is it somehow possible to search only for/through E-Mail?

Comment: Can't you use folderpath or any [email-specific attributes](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/searchcommands.htm#email) to distinguish mails from other item types?

Comment: E-Mail specific attribute was good thinking and I tried that already - I don't feel that to be a clean solution though.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In the search box, include `messageclass:IPM.Note` to find only e-mail messages.

Here is the full list (as far as I know) of message classes for Outlook/Exchange 2010 items.  I found some of this information in [Mastering Microsoft Exchange Server 2010](http://books.google.com/books?id=3fxuL9wBpr4C&pg=PA496&dq=outlook+2010+%22Message+Types+for+Managed+Content+Settings%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1tHzUvnvFKLXyAHQw4DwAQ&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=outlook%202010%20%22Message%20Types%20for%20Managed%20Content%20Settings%22&f=false) by Jim McBee and David Elfassy.  I found the rest by adding the "Message Class" column to an Outlook folder view and noting the values for different types of messages in that folder.

- **IPM.Activity:** Item in Outlook Journal folder
- **IPM.Appointment:** Item on Outlook Calendar
- **IPM.Contact:** Item in Outlook Contacts folder
- **IPM.Document:** Document/file (I don't believe this filter would ever yield results when searching Outlook e-mail)
- **IPM.Note:** E-mail message
- **IPM.Note.Rules.OofTemplate.Microsoft:** Received out-of-office auto reply e-mail
- **IPM.Note.SMIME:** Encrypted or digitally signed e-mail message
- **IPM.Note.Microsoft.Conversation:** Office Communication Server instant message or group chat session
- **IPM.Note.Microsoft.Conversation.Voice:** Office Communication Server call
- **IPM.Note.Microsoft.Fax:** Fax message
- **IPM.Note.Microsoft.Missed.Voice:** Notice of missed Office Communication Server call
- **IPM.Post:** Internet post item, usually for a public folder (I am unfamiliar with this one)
- **IPM.Post.RSS:** RSS feed
- **IPM.Schedule:** Meeting-related notice (will catch all of the specific types below)
- **IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Canceled:** Meeting cancellation notice
- **IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Notification.Forward**: Forwarded meeting invitation
- **IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request:** New or updated received meeting invitation
- **IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Resp.Neg:** Sent declined meeting notice
- **IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Resp.Pos:** Sent accepted meeting notice
- **IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Resp.Tent:** Sent tentative meeting notice
- **IPM.StickyNote:** Item in Outlook Notes folder
- **IPM.Task:** Item in Outlook Tasks folder
- **IPM.Note.Microsoft.Voicemail:** Voicemail left via Exchange 2007 Unified Messaging server or equivalent
- **IPM.Sharing:** The Sharing Message Object Protocol is used to share mailbox folders between clients. This protocol extends the Message and Attachment Object Protocol.
- **REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR:** Non-Delivery Report (NDR) aka bounce message

Comment: Woah! Quite the hotshot you are. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I'm glad that helped, though I know this question is pretty old now (sorry I was so late).  I use Outlook 2010 at work.  I wish more advanced search filters were incorporated into the Search Folder Criteria wizard--or they could have included a spot to paste a search string to use for a saved Search Folder.  But if you are patient, you can still accomplish a lot of what you want using the Search Box.

Comment: great :D, just a heads-up to all non-english users: propertynames are localized, but values are not. So with nb-NO locale it would be `meldingsklasse:IPM.Note`

Comment: This does not appear to work on OS X, fwiw

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with outlook web app - is there an equivalent?

Comment: For the record: The message class of Enterprise Vault "stubs" is `IPM.Note.EnterpriseVault.Shortcut`

Comment: Notice below there is an answer regarding localization/language-specific.

Comment: still a useful answer in 2023/4, thank you

Answer (score 10):

You should use this:

**[Message Class]:IPM.Note**

instead of

**messageclass:IPM.Note**

Because this variant doesn't work in other localization (non-english).

Comment: This should be a comment on hotshot309's answer (or a mod should incorporate it to their answer) as it's not an answer to the original question.

Comment: In fact, this did not work for my localization as I finally had to use `[Clase de mensaje]:”IPM.Schedule”`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method would be to type your query into the search box, then sort the results by icon. Emails automatically goto the top of the list, with everything else going to the bottom.

Comment: That is a good suggestion - I can even sort the mails by "Type". It would be great if I had a way to **only** search through mail though.

Comment: I agree, but I searched around and couldn't find the specific option you need. I think this might be as good as it gets.