# How to search for item type in Outlook Web App?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, outlook-web-access

I am looking to limit my search results to emails — or at least exclude Calendar items (invites & replies) — from my Outlook Web App search results.

The desktop app has `[Message Class]:IPM.Note` as per [How to search for item type in Outlook?](https://superuser.com/questions/555304/how-to-search-for-item-type-in-outlook)

What is the equivalent OWA construct? Any other Calendar-specific work-around? I've tried `folderpath:calendar` ([source](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/searchcommands.htm#email)), `NOT event` etc. without success.